# Setting an address and Initialization of a pointer

Tags: c

first, I'm sorry for my poor English, it's not my first language.

It's my first time to study about pointers and I found somthing really weird.

The book I'm reading says `*` marker means a variable that the 'pa' indicates.

But when I try and initialize a pointer

```
int a;
int *pA =&a;
```

(they used `*pA` in this case) and then change it,

> *pA=&a;

doesn't work, and

> pA=&a;

works.

So my query is "is there any difference between initializing pointers and just substituting?"

Comment: Ty, Think this place is awesome, people are kind and wise.

Hope i can be like ya'll and then I can help others in need at the c field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int a;
```

This allocates an integer on the stack

```
int* pA = &a;
```

This allocates an int pointer on the stack and sets its value to point to a.  The '*' is part of the declaration.

```
*pA = &a;
```

In this case the '*' is an operator that says "look where pA points", which is to an int.  You are then trying to set that int to the address of a, which is not allowed.

```
pA = &a;
```

Now this is the same as the second statement.  It sets the value of pA to point to a.

Comment: i'm also curious about when i'm allocating both a pointer and a variable.
> int a, *p1;<--like this
and it works! make me think that '*' is included to the pointer.

Comment: That's just shorthand for two separate declarations.  The * is still part of the declaration (int *) of p1.  I agree it's not completely intuitive, you just have to get used to it.  In a declaration the * is part of the type.  As an operator it has a different (but related) meaning.

Answer (score 1):

In C, **"declaration mimics use"**.

When you declare a pointer to `int`

```
int *pa;
```

you can see that `pa` is a `int *` or that `*pa` is a `int`.

You can assign pointers to int to `pa`, or you can assign ints to `*pa`.
That's why, after the above declaration, the following statements "work".

```
*pa = 42;
pa = &a;
```

In the declaration itself, you can "transform" it to a definition by supplying an initialization value. The definition is for the object `pa` of type `int*`, not for `*pa`.

```
int *pa = &a; /* initialize pa, which takes a `int*` */
pa = &b;      /* change `pa` with a different `int*` */
*pa = 42;     /* change the value pointed to by `pa` */
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create a pointer you use

`int *pA;`

Afterwards, using `*pA` means you're accessing the **value pointed to by the pointer**.

When you use `&a` you are using the [Address-of Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/64sa8b1e(VS.71).aspx) which returns the address of the memory location in which the data stored of the variable `a` (which is a integer) is stored.

So, the correct assignment is `pA = &a` since you're copying the address of `a` to `pA` which is supposed to hold addresses of memory locations.

But `*pA` represents the value in that memory location (an integer) so it is incorrect to assign an address to `*pA` - this is why the right syntax is `pA = &a`.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, when you first declare a pointer, you can specify the memory address. Because you are declaring it as a pointer, you use the `*` operator. But everywhere else, the `*pA` means to take the value referenced by that pointer (not the actual address). It is a little odd but you get used to it.

So, you can do this:

```
int a; 
int *pA = &a;
```

and you can do this:

```
pA = &a;
```

But you cannot do:

```
*pA = &a;
```

Because that says, "make the value pointed by `pA` = to the value of a."

However, you can do this:

```
*pA = a;
```

And that is just how you set the value pointed to by pA. Hope this is somewhat clear.